# ¿Cómo incluir un archivo .js dentro de otro archivo .js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un archivo de nombre iterop.js  y necesito incluir dentro de este los siguientes:

```
  <script src="/Content/js/global.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: dentro de tu archivo js utiliza `require('otro.js')`

Comment: @Christian incorrecto eso solo sirve para `nodeJS` y ciertos frameworks de javascript.

Comment: No seria usual no tener esos archivos `JS` de manera global, puesto que de todas formas lo normal e ideal es dejar esos archivos para todo el documento ademas algunas llamadas a otros requerimentos de tus frameworks pueden verse perdidas o erroneamente referenciadas si tratas de incluir esos dos archivos en un solo `script`,  yo te recomiendo que si solo se trata de frameworks los dejes global.

Comment: Hola @Riven... Es nesesesario debido a que la app es Blazor Assembly  y trabaja con el archivo interop.js  y alli deben estar referenciadas las funciones JS

Comment: Es en inglés, pero hay muchas respuestas aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file